# Date --set not permitted to user www-data

Tags: bash, debian, shell, php, lighttpd

I'm running a lighttpd server on Debian GNU/Linux 7.5 (wheezy) and want to use a php webpage to change the system time (I know I can just change the page's time, but that's not what I need for this project). Right now I'm using the `exec()` command to issue commands directly and to just run a shell script. So either:

`exec('date --set [HH:MM:SS]')`

or

`exec("sh /full/file/path/updateTime.sh") //contains command 'date --set [HH:MM:SS]'`

If I switch user on the command line to www-data and try to run the date command I get the response "date: cannot set date: Operation not permitted."

The shell script runs successfully if I run it as root.

If I provide a second argument to `exec()` to hold the response it contains the date/time information I'm trying to set.

I also tried editing sudoers to add

```
www-data        ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL
```

under `user privilege specification` and `includedir /etc/sudoers.d` with no change. I also tried creating a Cmnd alias specification for `/bin/date` and adding it to the www-data user with no change.

I'm pretty inexperienced with everything involved, so any help is appreciated.

The site won't be live, but I am aware of the dangers associated with accepting shell commands from users. I've checked the `php.ini` file to make sure that the `exec()` command isn't disabled. I've tried giving ownership of the shell script in `/var/www/` to www-data with no change. Permissions are set to 777 for now .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the www-data is in the sudoers file, you would state that the `sudo` command would not need a password, as www-data can't enter one.

The sudoers entry should be `www-data        ALL=(ALL:ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL`

Then you would need to run `sudo date --set [HH:MM:SS]` instead of just `date --set [HH:MM:SS]`.

**www-data should never have `sudo` rights unless you are just using it for your own personal development, on a test server. This is a big security loophole.**

Edit: Take a look at this question, which is simalar [sudo in php exec()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3173201/sudo-in-php-exec)

Comment: It'd be more secure (although still too dangerous for "real" use) to limit the what www-data can do to just `date --set` as root. I'm not sure I understand the sudoers syntax right, but I *think* it'd be "www-data ALL=(root) NOPASSWD: /bin/date --set" (and then use `exec('/usr/bin/suro /bin/date --set [HH:MM:SS]')`, although your paths may be slightly different).

Comment: @GordonDavisson, why do I need the `/usr/bin/sudo` portion added to the  argument in the `exec()` command? Is it because that's the location of the sudo command (Again, I'm learning a lot as I go so sorry if that sounds like a dumb question)?

Comment: Also, adding " --set"  in sudoers prevented www-data from sudoing anything, but just ending it at "/bin/date" worked. Thanks!

Comment: @Nick: I don't think it's really necessary to include the full path to `sudo` (or `date` either), I just prefer to include them in case the script runs with a weird `PATH` that doesn't include the relevant directories. As for the " --set" option causing trouble: it may be that you need to specify that another argument is allowed, like "/bin/date --set *", but if just leaving it off works I don't think that's significantly less secure.

Comment: @GordonDavisson, turns out my error was putting quotation marks around "/bin/date --set *" in sudoers. I'm not sure why I thought they should be there in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

Here’s another approach:

- Create a FIFO (named pipe) in a reasonably secure location —
  any place that’s not world-writable should be OK.
- Make it owned by `www-data`, mode 600. 
  Or 200 should work.
- Every time the PHP application wants to change the system time,
  have it write the new time to the FIFO.
- Have a daemon process, running as root, read from the FIFO. 
  When it reads a correctly formatted time, have it set the system clock.

No need to mess with `sudo`. 
The worst that can happen if somebody breaks into your system as `www-data`
is that he can write time changes to the FIFO
and cause the daemon to change the time. 
It seems to be just about impossible
that the attacker would be able to elevate his privileges to `root`
(unless you create a vulnerability in the daemon).